# Text animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, text

I'm trying to show the user several words (one after another), rhythmically, on the screen - like your average "Boom Booom Bap, silence" beat, and then repeat it again.

How would I go achieving something like this with jQuery?

I came up with a very lame code that has a plain rhythm, and don't know how to make the (silence) part / divide the words:

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {  
    
 var textlist = ["Boom","Booom", "Bap", "Hey","Yoh", "Aha", "Namean","Brooklyn", "Pizza"];
 
 var timer;
 function textFade(index){
  $("#container").html(textlist[index]).fadeIn(200);
  index++;
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
   textFade(index % textlist.length);
  }, 1500);
 }
   
 
 textFade(0);
 
 
});
```

```css
body{font-size: 90px;}
#container{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #eee;
font-family: 36px;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
display: none;
padding-top: 20px;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Using empty strings, like `["Boom","Booom", "Bap", "", "Hey","Yoh", "Aha", "", "Namean","Brooklyn", "Pizza", ""]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting up timeout conditionally.

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
        textFade(index % textlist.length);
    }, (index%3==0)?2000:700);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Prome Nabid mentions, the easiest solution would be to fill your gaps with empty string elements.

Inversely, you can also put more words into an element for faster beat text.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {  
    
 var textlist = ["Boom","Booom", "Bap", "", "", "", "Hey","Yoh", "The sound of my", "heart", "Namean","Brooklyn", "Pizza", ""];
 
 var timer;
 function textFade(index){
  $("#container").html(textlist[index]).fadeIn(200);
  index++;
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
   textFade(index % textlist.length);
  }, 1500);
 }
   
 
 textFade(0);
 
 
});
```

```css
body{font-size: 90px;}
#container{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: #eee;
font-family: 36px;
color: #333;
text-align: center;
display: none;
padding-top: 20px;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You can also replace the empty strings with a word to persist that word longer than 1 "beat" in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     
     var textlist = ["Boom","Booom", "Bap","","Hey","Yoh", "Aha", "Namean","Brooklyn", "Pizza"];
     
     var timer;
     
     function textFade(index){
         $("#container").html(textlist[index]).fadeIn(200);
         index++;
         timer = setTimeout(function() {
             textFade(index % textlist.length);
             }, (index===4) ? 4500 : 1500);
     }
   
 textFade(0);

 })
```

```css
 body {
   font-size: 90px;
 }
#container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  font-family: 36px;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```